# Derivative of eigenvectors of a matrix with respect to its components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, eigenvector, classical-mechanics, tensor

Suppose that $B$ is a real, positive-definitive symmetric ($3\times3$) matrix (more accurately, $B$ is a tensor) with distinct eigenvalues, and that we can write it as 
$$
B= \sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_{i}(n_{i}\otimes n_{i}),
$$
where $ n_{i} $ and $ \lambda_{i} $ are the unit eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $B$, and $\otimes$ is the [dyadic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics).

I need to calculate the derivative of eigenvectors of $B$ with respect to its components; in other words:
 $$
\frac{\partial n_{i}}{\partial B}
$$

I read some sources such as Kato's Perturbation theory but I couldn't figure out how to solve this, so I'm looking for pointers to a closed form solution.

Comment: are **B** and $B$ distinct objects?

Comment: This is definitely in Kato's book.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Dr.Beenakker I should apologize because of my misunderstanding. Both **B** and _B_ are the same Tensor and have three different eigenvalues. also, I should mention that the sign $\otimes$ means dyadic product.

Comment: I have edited so that **B** becomes $B$.  I have never heard of the dyadic product before, but the Wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics suggests that it is a tensor product, I guess after using the metric to identify $\mathbb R^3$ with its dual.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If $B$ depends on a single parameter $t$ then derivating  with respect to $t$  the equality

$$ B n_i =\lambda_i n_i $$

we deduce

$$\dot{B} n_i +B\dot{n}_i=\dot{\lambda}_i n_i +\lambda_i\dot{n}_i. $$

Here we assume that $\Vert n_i\Vert =1$.  Hence $\dot{n}_i\perp n_i$, $\forall i$. Taking the inner product of  the above equality with $n_i$  and observing that

$$ (B\dot{n}_i, n_i)=(\dot{n}_i, Bn_i)=\lambda_i(\dot{n}_i,n_i)=0 \tag{1} $$

we deduce

$$\boxed{\dot{\lambda}_i=(\dot{B}n_i,n_i).} $$

This determines $\dot{\lambda}_i$ in terms of $\dot{B}$.

Next, we take the inner product of (1)  with $n_j$, $j\neq i$.  Using the fact that $B$ is symmetric we deduce

$$(\dot{B}n_i, n_j)+(\dot{n}_i, Bn_j)=\lambda_i (\dot{n}_i, n_j) $$

so that

$$(\dot{B}n_i, n_j)+\lambda_j(\dot{n}_i, n_j)=\lambda_i (\dot{n}_i, n_j) $$

This shows that

$$(\dot{n}_i, n_j)=\frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}(\dot{B}n_i, n_j), $$

that is

$$\dot{n}_i=\sum_{j\neq i} \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}(\dot{B}n_i, n_j) n_j.\tag{2} $$

If we let the parameter  $t$ to be  entry $b_{k\ell}$, $k\leq \ell$,  of $B$  with respect to some fixed orthonormal basis we deduce

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial b_{k\ell}}=\sum_{j\neq i} \frac{1}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}\Biggl(\frac{\partial B}{\partial b_{k\ell}}n_i, n_j\Biggr) n_j.} $$

This is equivalent with the formula of Carlo Beenakker.

Comment: Dr. Nicolaescu I should apologize you. I guess because of my misunderstanding about Dr. Beenakker comment. In my question both **B** and _B_ are same. I've followed your straightforward calculation but I couldn't understand the very last line may I kindly ask you to explain it to me. Also, I should mention that the sign ⊗ means dyadic product

Comment: In math $\otimes$ signifies tensor product. To understand  the last equality observe that in (2) the   dot denotes the  derivative with respect to the parameter $t$. If we let $t=b_{k\ell}$  then $\dot{n}_i=\partial_t n_i=\partial_{b_{k\ell}}n_i$, $\dot{B}=\partial_t B=\partial_{b_{k\ell}} B$ and you get the last formula.

Comment: As a late follow-up question:
What happens if two eigenvalues are (nearly) the same?
For the eigenvalues, it seems to be no problem. But for the eigenvectors, it is, since the denominator is going to be (nearly) zero. Even if the eigenvectors are exchanging, at least expressions symmetric in them (eg. sum of eigenvectors), should be well defined. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Janos the eigenvalues of the 2x2 matrix $[(0,t),(t,0)]$ are $\lambda_1(t) =|t|$ and $\lambda_2(t) = -|t|$. Those functions of $t$ are not differentiable.

Answer (score 8):

first order perturbation theory in $\epsilon$ on the matrix **B** with elements $B_{nm}+\epsilon \delta_{nk}\delta_{ml}$ tells you that

$$\frac{d\vec{n}_i}{dB_{kl}}=\sum_{j\neq i}\frac{(\vec{n}_j)_k (\vec{n}_i)_l}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}\vec{n}_j$$

with $(\vec{n}_i)_l$ the $l$-th component of the vector $\vec{n}_i$.

Comment: follow-up question (for complex $B$) at https://mathoverflow.net/q/385159/11260