# Derivative of eigenvectors of an Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, eigenvector, hermitian

In the question "[Derivative of eigenvectors of a matrix with respect to its components](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229425)", [Liviu Nicolaescu](https://mathoverflow.net/a/229467/175010) has provided an answer valid for a real matrix. As outlined in the following, the same proof applies to Hermitian matrices, but it is incomplete.

Let us consider an Hermitian matrix $H$ ($H^\dagger = H$). Its eigenvectors satisfy

$$(H-\lambda_i) v_i = 0 \quad\text{with}\quad \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R} \quad\text{and}\quad v_j^\dagger v_i=\delta_{ij}.$$

From the derivative of the first relation one gets
$$(H - \lambda_i) \dot v_i + (\dot H - \dot \lambda_i) v_i = 0 \quad\rightarrow\quad \dot \lambda_i = v_i^\dagger \dot H v_i.$$

Considering the eigendecomposition of $\dot v_i$ combined with the previous equation, one gets
$$\dot v_i = \sum \alpha_{ij}v_j \quad\rightarrow\quad \alpha_{ij} = \frac{v_j^\dagger \dot H v_i}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j}\quad\text{for}\quad i\ne j.$$

From the derivative of $v_i^\dagger v_i=1$, one gets $Re(v_i^\dagger \dot v_i)=Re(\alpha_{ii})=0$.

So far everything is compatible with [the case of real matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/a/229467/175010), **BUT** what is the value of $Im(\alpha_{ii})$??

From numerical experiments I can surely state that $Im(\alpha_{ii})$ is non-zero and it has an order of magnitude compatible with the values of $\alpha_{ij}$. But I cannot find any way to derive its analytical expression.

Comment: Normalization does not determine $v_i$ uniquely, since you can always multiply by a complex number of modulus 1. If you want a unique eigenvector, you need to impose another constraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is first order perturbation theory, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#First_order_corrections). As explained there (search for "*Since the overall phase is not determined in quantum mechanics*"), you need to use the freedom you have to multiply the eigenstate by a complex phase vector, to ensure that $\alpha_{ii}$ is real and hence zero.

<sub>More precisely, the phase ambiguity is resolved by demanding that the inner product $\langle v_i^{(0)}|v_i^{(n)}\rangle$ of the zeroth order eigenstate $v_i^{(0)}$ and the $n$-th order correction $v_i^{(n)}$ is real  for each $n$. To first order this implies $\langle v_i^{(0)}|v_i^{(1)}\rangle=0$, but in higher order this overlap is nonzero. For example, $\langle v_i^{(0)}|v_i^{(2)}\rangle=-\tfrac{1}{2}\langle v_i^{(1)}|v_i^{(1)}\rangle$. [These notes](https://web.pa.msu.edu/people/mmoore/TIPT.pdf) gives a clear derivation.</sub>